# Get the first group of rows where specified column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an Approval table where there is a requestor, verifier and approver. Sometimes there are multiple verifiers in a certain request no:

```
RequestNo | UserName | Action    | Seq | ActionDate
R001      | JohnD    | Requestor | 1   |  01/01/2017
R001      | SamS     | Verifier  | 2   |  NULL
R001      | TrishL   | Verifier  | 3   |  NULL
R001      | GeorgeP  | Verifier  | 4   |  NULL
R001      | JackF    | Approver  | 5   |  NULL
```

What I need is to get the first Action group (Requestor, Verifier, Approver) with null value in ActionDate. I need to display the UserNames and Action under the first Action group with null ActionDate. In this case, it should be SamS, TrishL and GeorgeP. Thanks guys!

Comment: Is it possible that thers's another row like `R001      | BlaB     | Verifier  | 6   |  NULL`? Is there only one row with an ActionDate?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, that will not be possible. The approver will always be the last row in a RequestNo

Comment: what if one of the rows after the first null in verifier group has a non-null actionDate? do you still have to show all the rows in verifier group?

Comment: Then it will look for the next group with null ActionDate. Let's say TrishL from `Verifier` group has ActionDate populated, the query should now display JackF from Approver group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this should get you the info that you want:

```
Select UserName, Action
From ActionGroups
Where Action in (
  Select top 1 Action 
  from ActionGroups 
  Where ActionDate Is Null
  Order by Action
)
```

In this case, you are filtering by a subquery which returns the first Action (sorted alphabetically) that has a null `ActionDate`.

Comment: Thanks man! I put a `WHERE RequestNo = 'R001'` statement in both inside and outside query to achieve the desired result. Is that good sql code? Because if I will put WHERE statement in the inside SELECT, it will repeat the Verifiers multiple times. If I put the WHERE statement in the outside SELECT, it will only display the approver

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly but should get you what is needed. You first assign consecutive rows with the same action to a group. Then get the `max` and `min` date for each group. Then check if both the max and min dates are null and pick the first such group.

```
select requestno,username,action,seq,actiondate 
from (select t.*
      ,min(case when maxdate is null and mindate is null then grp end) over(partition by requestno) as first_grp 
      from (select t.*
            ,max(actiondate) over(partition by requestno,grp) as maxdate
            ,min(actiondate) over(partition by requestno,grp) as mindate
            from (select t.*,sum(col) over(partition by requestno order by seq) as grp
                  from (select t.*
                        ,case when lag(action) over(partition by requestno order by seq)=action then 0 else 1 end as col
                        from t
                       ) t
                  ) t
           )t 
      ) t 
where first_grp=grp
```

Comment: When there are only NULLs within a group you don't have to check both min & max :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using the below query.

declare @tbl table
(
ReqNO varchar(10),
Username varchar(10),
[Action] varchar(20),
Seq bit,
[Date] datetime null
)

insert into @tbl values ('R001','JohnD','Requestor',1,'01/01/2017')
insert into @tbl values ('R001','SamS','Verifier',2,null)
insert into @tbl values ('R001','TrishL','Verifier',3,null)
insert into @tbl values ('R001','GeorgeP','Verifier',4,null)
insert into @tbl values ('R001','JackF','Approver',5,null)

--select * from @tbl

select t.Username from @tbl t where t.Action in(
select d.Action from @tbl d  where d.Date is null 
--and ReqNO='R001' 
group by (d.Action) having COUNT(d.Action)>1)
```